# SQL query to multiple tables for the most recent data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL query at the moment is:

```
select 
    t.ZoneNumber, t.Mode, t.DeviceA, t.DeviceB, t.LevelA, t.LevelB,
    t.Counter, t.Options, t.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device, t.AzureDeviceID,
    t.TimeStamp,
    tt.ZoneName, tt.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device, tt.ZoneNumber, tt.TimeStamp 
from 
    [dbo].[tblZone] t, [dbo].[tblZoneName] tt   
inner join 
    (select 
         ZoneNumber, max(TimeStamp) as MaxDate 
     from
         [dbo].[tblZone] 
     where 
         AzureDeviceID_Field_Device like 'myFirstDevicea' 
     group by 
         ZoneNumber) tm on t.ZoneNumber = tm.ZoneNumber and t.TimeStamp = tm.MaxDate
```

What I am trying to do is query two or more tables at the same time for the most recent records on each table based on the DeviceID which is AzureDeviceID_Field_Device and Zonenumber.

For my example my DeviceID which is also a KEY is "myFirstDevicea". It will produce records of multiple Zones,each zone has a number e.g. 1 to 10. For each zone number i would like to produce only the most recent.

tblZone has zone parameters, and tbl zonename as the name the zone is been given.  This name can change from time to time.

So my aim is to produce a recent list from tablezone, which i can do and then get the most recent name given from table zonename.

When I run the query, I am getting various could not bound errors?

Can someone help me out in regards to this query.

tblZone

[image]

tableZoneName

[image]

```
  select t.ZoneNumber,t.Mode,t.DeviceA,t.DeviceB,t.LevelA,t.LevelB,t.Counter,t.Options,t.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device,t.AzureDeviceID,t.TimeStamp
  from [dbo].[tblZone] t
  inner join (select ZoneNumber, max(TimeStamp) as MaxDate FROM [dbo].[tblZone] WHERE AzureDeviceID_Field_Device LIKE 'myFirstDevicea' group by ZoneNumber )tm 
  on  t.ZoneNumber = tm.ZoneNumber and t.TimeStamp = tm.MaxDate 

  select tt.ZoneName,tt.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device,tt.ZoneNumber,tt.TimeStamp
  from  [dbo].[tblZoneName] tt 
  inner join (select ZoneNumber, max(TimeStamp) as MaxDate FROM [dbo].[tblZoneName] WHERE AzureDeviceID_Field_Device LIKE 'myFirstDevicea' group by ZoneNumber )tm 
  on  tt.ZoneNumber = tm.ZoneNumber and tt.TimeStamp = tm.MaxDate
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi, is AzureDeviceID_Field_Device column belong to both  [dbo].[tblZone] and [dbo].[tblZoneName] ? Seems, you use that column for both of them. Pls, add your table's picture for more help .

Comment: Just posted images of the table 
AzureDeviceID_Field_Device is UID for the zone device

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using derived tables within a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), utilising [windowed functions](https://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/) to identify the most recent `TimeStamp` value in both tables:

```
-- Built test data:
declare @tblZone table(AzureDeviceID_Field_Device nvarchar(100),Zonenumber int, [TimeStamp] datetime2);
declare @tableZoneName table(AzureDeviceID_Field_Device nvarchar(100),ZoneNumber int, ZoneName nvarchar(100), [TimeStamp] datetime2);
insert into @tblZone values ('a1',1 ,getdate()-2),('a1',1 ,getdate()-1),('a1',1 ,getdate()),('a1',15,getdate()-4),('a1',15,getdate()-3),('a1',15,getdate()-2);
insert into @tableZoneName values ('a1',1 ,'Zone A1',getdate()-2),('a1',1 ,'Zone A1',getdate()-1),('a1',1 ,'Zone A1',getdate()),('a1',15,'Zone A15',getdate()-4),('a1',15,'Zone A15',getdate()-3),('a1',15,'Zone A15',getdate()-2);

-- Common Table Expressions (CTE) to add a Row Number to both tables:
with z as
(
    select AzureDeviceID_Field_Device
            ,Zonenumber
            ,[TimeStamp]    -- row_number() returns the order the rows are in, grouped by the PARTITION columns and ordered by the ORDER BY colmns
            ,row_number() over (partition by AzureDeviceID_Field_Device, ZoneNumber
                                order by [TimeStamp] desc
                               ) as rn
    from @tblZone
),zn as
(
    select AzureDeviceID_Field_Device
            ,Zonenumber
            ,ZoneName
            ,[TimeStamp]
            ,row_number() over (partition by AzureDeviceID_Field_Device, ZoneNumber
                                order by [TimeStamp] desc
                               ) as rn
    from @tableZoneName
)
-- Join the two derived tables together to get your result:
select *
from z
    left join zn
        on z.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device = zn.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device
            and z.ZoneNumber = zn.Zonenumber
            and zn.rn = 1    -- Rows with a rn value of one will have the most recent TimeStamp.
where z.rn = 1
order by z.AzureDeviceID_Field_Device
        ,z.ZoneNumber;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------+----+----------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| AzureDeviceID_Field_Device | Zonenumber |          TimeStamp          | rn | AzureDeviceID_Field_Device | Zonenumber | ZoneName |          TimeStamp          | rn |
+----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------+----+----------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| a1                         |          1 | 2017-10-23 09:33:43.3066667 |  1 | a1                         |          1 | Zone A1  | 2017-10-23 09:33:43.3233333 |  1 |
| a1                         |         15 | 2017-10-21 09:33:43.3066667 |  1 | a1                         |         15 | Zone A15 | 2017-10-21 09:33:43.3233333 |  1 |
+----------------------------+------------+-----------------------------+----+----------------------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
```

Comment: thank you, will try to run so i understand it better.

Comment: If i need to add more table to query , must i alter anything in particular?

Comment: Just add another derived table in the same way that tables `z` and `zn` have been defined.

Comment: Once table is added, how do i integrate it to the left join process.?

Comment: I now have about 11 tables, but i am finding the querying is taking some time. Would you be able to advice how to speed it up

Comment: Sounds like you need to pre process your data before querying or change your data structures

Comment: I am very new to SQL. Is there an example i could follow  or do ?

Comment: Would it be better to Query each table seperately and then process and sort the results Afterwards?

Comment: The use of `row_number() over()` as shown here by iamdave is entirely appropriate for your question. Expanding the query to 11 tables and experiencing slowness isn't relevant to this question. It is a new question and on that new question include the query `execution plan` and information about indexes on each table. Attempting any performance tuning without that information will just be guesses.

Comment: Just one point I'd like to make is that using `common table expressions` (CTEs) isn't required in this answer as it could also be done using regular derived tables (subqueries) with the same `execution plan`